# How to find smallest enclosing ellipse when multiple lines are given ? This ellipse needs to intersect all those lines

Tags: matrices, geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

I'm trying to find the smallest ellipse in terms of circumference. I suspect the smallest enclosing ellipse will intersect some lines in one single point. Given a line *l: px + qy + r =* 0 ,  *L* : {*p  q  r*}

I can try to find this ellipse by using the following equation: *ap<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub> + bp<sub>n</sub>q<sub>n</sub> + cq<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub> + dp<sub>n</sub>r<sub>n</sub> + eq<sub>n</sub>r<sub>n</sub> + fr<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub> =* 0. Whereby *n* represents the number of lines. Using multiple lines I can find the values of *a ... f*.

Later I can use the following equation *K:* *LBL<sup>T</sup>=* 0 , whereby *B* contains the parameters *a ... f*. I was actually wondering if there was a simpler or more elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: Just to be sure, *smallest* means *with the smallest area*, right? Interesting question; I wouldn't bet that we may find the optimal solution in a fast way, maybe reasonable approximations are easier to find.

Comment: By *smallest ellipse* I meant, *smallest perimeter*. If there is another way to get a better definition of the smallest, please let me know.